# What is the proper way to convert depth map into a png image?

Tags: image, 3d, computer-vision, point-clouds

I am trying to use a depth map (numpy array) to create a point cloud using open3d. To do so, I need to convert the depth map into a png image. I want to know what is the proper way to do this.

The depth map is a 500x500 numpy array with values between `(0, 10)`.

I have corresponding rgb image and I want to make a pointcloud using the depth map and rgb image using open3d.